# initializing a ruby bit-struct with pack

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a way to initialize a bit-struct object in ruby.

Here's my class:

```
class MyBitStruct < BitStruct
    default_options :endian => :little
    unsigned :len,      16, "Length of message including this field"
    unsigned :msgType,  8,  "0x2"
    unsigned :status,   8,  "Response, A for success"

    def initialize(pkt = nil)
        if(pkt == nil)
            @len        = 32
            @msgType    = 2 
            @status     = 'A'
        else
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

I'd like to do the following (in initialize):

```
self < [32,2,"A"].pack("vcA")
```

But this doesn't work.  Is what I'm trying to do possible, or is there a more terse method than what's in my initialize?